# how to print Clojure time elapsed function on JTextArea

Tags: time, clojure, hashmap

I have a JTextArea called 'output-text' and I would like to append the time elapsed to execute the function 'transfer-all', but it doesn't work

```
 (defn transfer-all []
    (doseq [i my-map]
      (transfer i account-destination money)
      )
  )
    ...

  (.append output-text (str (time (transfer-all))))
```

Any suggestion? Many Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(time expr) doesn't return the time it took to execute expr, it just prints it (and returns the value of expr).

You want `(with-out-str (time ...))`

Comment: thanks so much my code now is: (.append output-text (with-out-str  (time (transfer account-a account-b 100)))) ....and works. But I have problem with the 'transfer-all' function (as before): I'd like to perform an operation called 'transfer(from, to, amount)' for every element in my map...could you check what is wrong? thanks again

Comment: @nuvio please start a new question rather than piggy-back on this one